# How can I pass an array of URLs consecutively to $.Ajax URL?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, url, each

```
var a;
var urlArray = [];

$("a").each{function(){ 
    a = $(this).attr("href"); 
    urlArray.push(a);
});

var sArray = [];

$.each(urlArray, function(x, y){
         $.ajax({
               url: y, // pass the URLs consecutively
               type: 'get',
               dataType: 'html',
               success: function(data){
                   sArray.push( $("video").attr("src") );
                }
         })
});

log(sArray); // returns a single URL, not array as expected
```

I've been attempting to retrieve `src` values of `<video>` elements via `$.Ajax` calls. I try and pass an array of URLs consecutively to `$.Ajax` via `$.each`, but results logged from `success:` only come from a single URL. I expect an array returned, but am only able to `.push` one value into **sArray**.

Can someone explain how I can manage to consecutively retrieve the data I need from each URL sent to $.Ajax? Thank you.

***Note:** Put simply, I need to pass an array of URLs to $.Ajax so that I can retrieve data from every one of those URLs.*

Comment: `array.push()` returns the length of the array. So `var urlArray = urlArray.push(a);` doesn't do what you think.

Comment: I've edited the top.

Comment: You probably want the `push` inside the `each` function.